# How to use Xpath in PostgreSQL to extract html Attributes?

Tags: html, xml, postgresql, parsing, xpath

I'm dealing with column that just stores the HTML href tags in the format shown below.
There are no other tags beside the href tags.

`<a href='https://www.website1.ca/en/Section1/Section2/Section3/Section-4---Section5-R-Zone.pdf'>B4</a>`

I'm trying to extract the link from the HTML tag: https://www.website1.ca/en/Section1/Section2/Section3/Section-4---Section5-R-Zone.pdf

I'm not sure what Xpath expression to use. I've tried using the following to get the value inside the HTML attribute but it doesn't seem to work.

```
select
xpath(
'/href',
$$<a href='https://www.website1.ca/en/Section1/Section2/Section3/Section-4---Section5-R-Zone.pdf'>B4</a>$$,
'/@href'
);
```

Is there a xpath expression to get the value inside of the HTML attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Your XPATH query is wrong. Use this query to get all `href` attributes of all `a` tags:

```
SELECT xpath(
          '//a/@href',
           $$<a href='https://www.website1.ca/en/Section1/Section2/Section3/Section-4---Section5-R-Zone.pdf'>B4</a>$$
       );

                                          xpath                                          
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 {https://www.website1.ca/en/Section1/Section2/Section3/Section-4---Section5-R-Zone.pdf}
(1 row)
```

The result is an array with all the results (there could be several such tags).

Comment: Thanks for answer! What if there are two href attributes that need to be parsed. Is there a way to do all one in query? For Example: <a href='https://www.website1.ca/en/Section1/Section2/Section3/Section-4---Section5-R-Zone.pdf'>B4</a>, <a href='https://www.website2.ca/en/section1/section2/section3/Section-42---List-of-Things.pdf#page=48'>(26)</a>.

Is there a way to get the two URLs like: 'https://www.website1.ca/en/Section1/Section2/Section3/Section-4---Section5-R-Zone.pdf' AS URL1 AND 'https://www.website2.ca/en/section1/section2/section3/Section-42---List-of-Things.pdf#page=48' AS URL2.

Comment: That will work just fine and return both values. If you don't want an array, use `unnest`.